# Does Apache Jena evict tdb cache?

Tags: jena, tdb

I'm using apache jena with TDB. I just read some code from jena 3.9.0, it seems TDB using mmap to speed up query(MappedByteBuffer). But I have seen block(MappedByteBuffer) only grows but not shrik. Does this cause memory problem?

Answer (score 1):

It should not be a problem.

Memory mapped files are controlled by the operation system as to how much of the file is copied into RAM (the file system cache). The OS flexes the amount of space used, up and down, based on system resources and application demand.